# Mongodb replicaset election when successive priority is set for all nodes

Tags: mongodb

What would be given priority in mongodb replicaset's election process - priority or votes ? I mean, if I have successive priority set for all member nodes of a replicaset, will it ever go into a deadlock?

For instance, if I have a mongodb replicaset with 4 nodes and no arbiter. All of them have priority set, like node01 has 25, node02 has 20, node03 has 15, and node04 has 10.

Is there any chance of a deadlock in the election process, in the above case?

Comment: Don't use an even number of voting replica set members. The priorities can't cause deadlock, but if the set is split in half by a network partition then neither group of 2 will be able to elect a primary.

Comment: wdberkeley, I am aware of the disadvantages of having even number replica nodes. I gave a hypothetical situation.

Comment: Ok, cool. Just want to be sure :D

Answer (score 2):

In a given replica set with 4 nodes and their corresponding priority :=> node1:25,node2:20,node3:15,node4:10. Let us say node1(primary,with the highest priority) has gone down then elections will be triggered and node2 will be elected as the next primary(in order of priority) provided that it *receives votes from a majority members of the replica set*. Even theoretically there is no possibility of a deadlock. Setting non-defaut priority values for a replica set node might be useful when you want a node to be the preferred 'primary' node during election/failover.

Note - Since v2.6 of mongoDB every eligible node can vote only once.

Answer (score 0):

Votes and priority are two different things..
Mongo needs more than 50% of votes to elect a primary, if we have less than 50% of votes then all alive nodes become secondary.

Priority setting of replica set ensure that higher priority members are more likely to become primary than others which have low priority.

Node1:25 > Node2:20 > Node3:15 > Node4:10 is the sequence of your primaries.

NOTE:

1. you can set priority between 0 and 1000.
2. you can have only 7 voting members in a replica set cluster. Set votes to 0 for the additional members.

And for you questions:

What would be given priority in mongodb replicaset's election process - priority or votes ?

Ans: votes

I mean, if I have successive priority set for all member nodes of a replicaset, will it ever go into a deadlock?
Ans: Never.